# How to make regional date formats using Excel::Writer::XLSX

Tags: perl, date

I use the Excel::Writer::XLSX module to generate excel report, but the date format does not change according to different regions.

For example, if I set the region to 'English-United States', the date format should be 'mm/dd/yyyy' shown on excel sheet, if I reset the region to 'French-France', the date format should be 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

So I'd like to know how it is implemented using Excel::Writer::XLSX. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores a limited number of date formats with regional settings. For example in the number format dialog in Excel you will see a warning like this:

> Displays date and time serial numbers as date values, according to the type and locale (location) that you specify. Date formats that begin with an asterisk (*) respond to changes in regional date and time settings that are specified in Control Panel. Formats without an asterisk are not affected by Control Panel settings.

In Excel::Writer::XLSX you can set these using a `num_format` id number instead of a format string. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook   = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'dates.xlsx' );
my $worksheet  = $workbook->add_worksheet( 'Demo' );

$worksheet->set_column('A:A', 20);


# Regional date format.
my $date_format_1 = $workbook->add_format( num_format => 14 );

# Non-regional date format.
my $date_format_2 = $workbook->add_format( num_format => 'dd/mm/yy' );

$worksheet->write_date_time( 'A1', '2013-10-27T', $date_format_1 );
$worksheet->write_date_time( 'A2', '2013-10-27T', $date_format_2 );

__END__
```

See the [num_format section of the docs](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#set_num_format%28%29) for more examples of the builtin format ids.

Comment: I know the module does not support auto fit in column width. But I'd like to know if the date format does not also auto fit when you set different regions in system?

Comment: Modified answer to address the regional date issue.

Comment: Thanks jmcnamara. The problem has been fixed according to your solution.